# Using IEnumerable<T> type in parameter of method

Tags: c#, collections, parameters, ienumerable

Previously I used `IEnumerable<T>` type, if I passed collection as parameter of method.

But recently, I had a problem with the collection of type `IEnumerable<T>` that was created in similar way:

```
var peoples = names.Select(name => new People(name));
```

In this case, always, if I use a collection peoples (for example, foreach), it creates new instance of class People, and it can easily cause an error.

So I want to ask whether it is right to use the `IEnumerable <T>` type parameter. I think it may cause problems (see example above) and this type should not be used. What alternatives do you recommend (`ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>` etc.) and when to use which alternative?

Or do you think that this is a silly question, because the creation of objects in the Select method uses only a fool?

Of course, I know that I can use `ToArray()` or `ToList()` and thus solve the problem. But someone else who uses this method, it can not know. I would like to know how to prevent this by selecting the correct type parameter. List or array is too specific for me when I want to just "enumerate" objects.

Comment: What kind of error you could get by using `new People(name)`?

Comment: Wiktor Zychla: Problem: When I use peoples, it always creates a new instances of class People.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is not a collection. It is just something that you can "enumerate". The problem is not passing `IEnumerable` to your method, the problem is that if you are using LINQ (`Select` method), every time you read the enumerable it will execute the code again. If you only want to have it executed once, you can use the `ToArray()` or `ToList()` methods:

```
var peoples = names.Select(name => new People(name)).ToList();
```

Like this you can still pass it to any method accepting an `IEnumerable` (or `List`) and it will only create one instance for each person.

**Edit:**
Your method shouldn't worry about these kind of problems. It's the callers problem. There might be perfectly good reasons to call your method with an enumerable instead of a list. The caller should know that the enumerable gives different results if he passes it to different methods, so you shouldn't worry about that.

The only exception is if you enumerate the parameter more than once in the method itself. In this case you should cache the parameter in a list inside the method and then enumerate the list instead as many times as you need.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, LINQ does use deferred execution, so it won't actually execute until you attempt to pull something from an enumerable, which jives with your answer. But it won't rerun the query every time you access the enumerable. So you could put a LINQ statement in the loop expression of a foreach and it will only run the query once. Microsoft's gone to great lengths to optimize this.

Comment: Yes, but if you use 2 foreach statements accessing the enumerable if will reevaluate the query twice.

Comment: I guess I missed the part where two foreach statements were involved with this question. Sorry dude, I'm not trying to be mean, just want to make sure we're giving an accurate answer.

Comment: I edited question: Of course, I know that I can use ToArray () or ToList () and thus solve the problem. But someone else who uses this method, it can not know. I would like to know how to prevent this by selecting the correct type parameter. List or array is too specific for me when I want to just "enumerate" objects.

Comment: I think that this answer is to the point. As I see it, OP is worried that when  looping twice over the LINQ collection, items in it get created twice. That's just what @aKzenT says and correctly advises that `ToList` should be used. OP, what exactly do you mean when you say "I would like to know how to prevent this by selecting the correct type parameter."? I think that misundersanting stems exactly from here.

Comment: @MV1893 this is your callers problem, not the problem of your method. Your method should just enumerate the parameter like it did before and not worry on how it got the enumerable. Exception is if your method enumerates the parameter more than once. In this case you should cache the enumerable in a list inside the method.

Comment: aKzenT: Thanks. "Your method shouldn't worry about these kind of problems. It's the callers problem." Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

The `ToArray` and `ToList` suggestions expose more than what one might initially think. We're tempted to think of this advice as simply saying that calling `ToList`/`ToArray` at either the call-site or the first thing in your method corrects the issue, but your question is whether `IEnumerable<T>` is appropriate - you could change from a parameter type from `IEnumerable<T>` to something else (like `ICollection<T>`) which puts the onus on the caller to convert to something that implements this interface (note that `T[]`, `List<T>`, `IList<T>` and `Collection<T>` all do). Part of the problem with this approach is that these interfaces represent mutable collections, whereas `IEnumerable<T>` advertises that the method enumerates items - just one of the reasons I don't like this approach.

What if the potential bug was not really a bug at all? Perhaps the caller intends these to be defensive copies or dumb-data objects - in these latter cases, it may be inefficient by some measure but so is requiring them to make a copy - but in this proposed use it definitely is not a bug. Likewise, a one-size fits all recommendation doesn't fit because `IEnumerable<T>` objects don't have to ever terminate - but requiring an array type to be passed-in would mean that infinite (i.e. computed) or merely large `IEnumerable<T>` objects would be out of the question.

Regardless, I think you're right to pose questions regarding defensive programming. However, in this case I think the best solution is to stick with `IEnumerable<T>` and educate rather than limit your callers based on the speculation that they might, in some limited circumstances, introduce a bug.

Paraphrasing a quote:

> The problem with designing to prevent issues that idiots will make is that the idiots are so damned ingenious.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: The idea that this is not a bug, but the desired behavior is very interesting, it never occurred to me. Thank you, I will continue to use IEnumerable <T> in these cases. And your quote is perfect. :)